# ActivityManager Process has died issue

Tags: android

My app contains 5 screens. In the first screen, I load some data from the server and show those data in a listview in the second screen. In the listview I have to show an image for each row. These images are downloaded dynamically and is being cached too. Downloading happens in the background and I have given notifyDataSetChanged() for the list view.

When the downloading is inprogress, I can move onto the other 3 screens. In these 3 screens, I have a button which does the same functionality, i.e show a dialog which contains the same list as in my second screen.

The problem is when I choose a value from this dialog, say 2 or 3 times, the current activity disappears and it automatically moves onto my second page.

I am not able to identify the reason behind it. Please see the log which I get. Can anyone please tell why this issue is happening?

```
> 08-25 10:44:31.505: WARN/AudioFlinger(2573): write blocked for 73 msecs, 92 delayed writes, thread 0x5e518
08-25 10:44:31.515: DEBUG/szipinf(17236): Initializing inflate state
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9100/GT-I9100:2.3.3/GINGERBREAD/XWKE8:user/release-keys'
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421): pid: 17236, tid: 17236  >>> com.test.android <<<
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  r0 00000027  r1 deadbaad  r2 a0000000  r3 00000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  r4 00000001  r5 00000000  r6 bea102c0  r7 0000a000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  r8 00646278  r9 00030000  10 00000000  fp bea1022c
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  ip afd46688  sp bea100e0  lr afd19471  pc afd15f40  cpsr 68000030
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d0  fffff7d600000d72  d1  40e3100000000800
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d2  40b9f00000000000  d3  c14fec0040535000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d4  40e31000c182a600  d5  0000000000000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d6  4557200000071880  d7  45000000c502a000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  4680000046800000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d10 0000000042d2aaaa  d11 0000000000000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d16 00000000000000a0  d17 40e631e000000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d18 3faeb851e0000000  d19 3fc3333340000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d20 3fe3333340000000  d21 3fd3333340000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d22 3fd51eb860000000  d23 40e01d100abe0000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d24 40dd4c2013880000  d25 40ed4c1013880000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d26 40cd4c4013880000  d27 0000000000000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d28 0002d4740002d474  d29 407c300000000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421):  scr 80000012
08-25 10:44:31.695: INFO/AudioFlinger(2573): stop output streamType (0, 1) for 1
08-25 10:44:31.695: DEBUG/AudioHardwareYamaha(2573): AudioStreamOut::setParameters(keyValuePairs="stop_output_streamtype=1")
08-25 10:44:31.735: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #00  pc 00015f40  /system/lib/libc.so
08-25 10:44:31.735: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #01  pc 000138b0  /system/lib/libc.so
08-25 10:44:31.735: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #02  pc 00014776  /system/lib/libc.so
08-25 10:44:31.735: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #03  pc 0005079c  /system/lib/libskia.so
08-25 10:44:31.735: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #04  pc 0005089c  /system/lib/libskia.so
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #05  pc 0007d164  /system/lib/libskia.so
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #06  pc 0007d220  /system/lib/libskia.so
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #07  pc 0007d360  /system/lib/libskia.so
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #08  pc 0007d808  /system/lib/libskia.so
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421):          #09  pc 00080344  /system/lib/libskia.so
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421): code around pc:
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd15f20 2c006824 e028d1fb b13368db c064f8df 
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd15f30 44fc2401 4000f8cc 49124798 25002027 
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd15f40 f7f57008 2106eb46 ecbaf7f6 460aa901 
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd15f50 f04f2006 95015380 95029303 e820f7f6 
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd15f60 462aa905 f7f62002 f7f5e82c 2106eb32 
08-25 10:44:31.740: INFO/DEBUG(16421): code around lr:
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd19450 4a0e4b0d e92d447b 589c41f0 26004680 
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd19460 686768a5 f9b5e006 b113300c 47c04628 
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd19470 35544306 37fff117 6824d5f5 d1ef2c00 
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd19480 e8bd4630 bf0081f0 000280cc ffffff88 
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421): afd19490 b086b570 f602fb01 9004460c a804a901 
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421): stack:
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100a0  afd42684  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100a4  000afba8  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100a8  00000015  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100ac  afd18539  /system/lib/libc.so
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100b0  afd4272c  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100b4  afd426d8  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100b8  00000000  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100bc  afd19471  /system/lib/libc.so
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100c0  00000001  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100c4  bea100f4  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100c8  bea102c0  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100cc  0000a000  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100d0  00646278  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100d4  afd18793  /system/lib/libc.so
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100d8  df002777  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100dc  e3a070ad  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421): #00 bea100e0  00000000  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100e4  0017d908  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100e8  0017d8c0  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100ec  002b1d30  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100f0  bea102c0  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100f4  fffffbdf  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100f8  00646278  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea100fc  afd46470  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea10100  002b1d30  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea10104  afd138b5  /system/lib/libc.so
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421): #01 bea10108  0017d8c0  
08-25 10:44:31.745: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea1010c  002b1d30  
08-25 10:44:31.750: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea10110  ab217314  
08-25 10:44:31.750: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea10114  002b30f8  
08-25 10:44:31.750: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea10118  00646278  
08-25 10:44:31.750: INFO/DEBUG(16421):     bea1011c  afd14779  /system/lib/libc.so
08-25 10:44:32.140: INFO/BootReceiver(2689): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
08-25 10:44:32.145: INFO/DEBUG(16421): dumpstate /data/log/dumpstate_app_native.txt
08-25 10:44:32.150: INFO/dumpstate(17848): begin
08-25 10:44:32.165: INFO/dalvikvm(2689): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.170: INFO/dalvikvm(2689): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.170: INFO/dalvikvm(2810): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.170: INFO/dalvikvm(2810): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.170: INFO/dalvikvm(2832): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.175: INFO/dalvikvm(2832): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.175: INFO/dalvikvm(2836): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.175: INFO/dalvikvm(2836): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.175: INFO/dalvikvm(2837): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.175: INFO/dalvikvm(2837): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.180: INFO/dalvikvm(2838): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.180: INFO/dalvikvm(2838): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.180: INFO/dalvikvm(2840): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.180: INFO/dalvikvm(2840): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.180: INFO/dalvikvm(2846): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.200: ERROR/yamaha::media::Parameters(2573): SalesCode = INU
08-25 10:44:32.240: INFO/dalvikvm(2846): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.240: INFO/dalvikvm(2916): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.245: INFO/dalvikvm(2916): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.245: INFO/dalvikvm(2962): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.250: INFO/dalvikvm(2962): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.250: INFO/dalvikvm(3104): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.250: INFO/dalvikvm(3104): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.250: INFO/dalvikvm(3238): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.250: INFO/dalvikvm(3238): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.250: INFO/dalvikvm(3405): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.255: INFO/dalvikvm(3405): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.255: INFO/dalvikvm(3461): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.255: INFO/dalvikvm(3461): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.255: INFO/dalvikvm(3503): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.255: INFO/dalvikvm(3503): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.255: INFO/dalvikvm(3574): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.255: INFO/dalvikvm(3574): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.255: INFO/dalvikvm(3594): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.260: INFO/dalvikvm(3594): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.260: INFO/dalvikvm(3602): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.260: INFO/dalvikvm(3602): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.260: INFO/dalvikvm(3633): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.265: INFO/dalvikvm(3633): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.265: INFO/dalvikvm(3644): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.265: INFO/dalvikvm(3644): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.265: INFO/dalvikvm(5258): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.270: INFO/dalvikvm(5258): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.270: INFO/dalvikvm(6665): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.270: INFO/dalvikvm(6665): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.270: INFO/dalvikvm(12988): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.275: INFO/dalvikvm(12988): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.275: INFO/dalvikvm(13199): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.275: INFO/dalvikvm(13199): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.275: INFO/dalvikvm(13271): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.275: INFO/dalvikvm(13271): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.275: INFO/dalvikvm(13304): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.280: INFO/dalvikvm(13304): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.280: INFO/dalvikvm(13332): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.280: INFO/dalvikvm(13332): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.280: INFO/dalvikvm(13342): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.280: INFO/dalvikvm(13342): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.280: INFO/dalvikvm(13352): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.280: INFO/dalvikvm(13352): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.280: INFO/dalvikvm(13366): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.285: INFO/dalvikvm(13366): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.285: INFO/dalvikvm(13374): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.285: INFO/dalvikvm(13374): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.285: INFO/dalvikvm(13403): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.285: INFO/dalvikvm(13403): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.285: INFO/dalvikvm(13608): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.285: INFO/dalvikvm(13608): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.290: INFO/dalvikvm(13866): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.290: INFO/dalvikvm(13866): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.290: INFO/dalvikvm(13897): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.290: INFO/dalvikvm(13897): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.290: INFO/dalvikvm(14304): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.290: INFO/dalvikvm(14304): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.290: INFO/dalvikvm(14471): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.295: INFO/dalvikvm(14471): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.295: INFO/dalvikvm(17236): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.495: INFO/dalvikvm(17511): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.500: INFO/dalvikvm(17511): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.505: INFO/dalvikvm(17583): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.515: INFO/dalvikvm(17583): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.515: INFO/dalvikvm(17595): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.520: INFO/dalvikvm(17595): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.520: INFO/dalvikvm(17620): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.535: INFO/dalvikvm(17620): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.540: INFO/dalvikvm(17653): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.550: INFO/dalvikvm(17653): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.550: INFO/dalvikvm(17664): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.560: INFO/dalvikvm(17664): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.560: INFO/dalvikvm(17672): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.570: INFO/dalvikvm(17672): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.570: INFO/dalvikvm(17689): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.580: INFO/dalvikvm(17689): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.580: INFO/dalvikvm(17696): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-25 10:44:32.600: INFO/dalvikvm(17696): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-25 10:44:32.795: ERROR/lights(2689): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 2
08-25 10:44:32.795: WARN/PowerManagerService(2689): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
08-25 10:44:32.795: INFO/PowerManagerService(2689): Ulight 7->3|0
08-25 10:44:32.795: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2689): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
08-25 10:44:33.295: WARN/dalvikvm(17236): threadid=4: spin on suspend #1 threadid=13 (pcf=0)
08-25 10:44:33.760: INFO/ALSAModule(2573): Terminated ALSA PLAYBACK device hifi
08-25 10:44:34.180: ERROR/yamaha::media::Parameters(2573): SalesCode = INU
08-25 10:44:35.955: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3104): GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 55% free 2593K/5703K, external 0K/0K, paused 37ms
08-25 10:44:36.025: DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(2565): asec list
08-25 10:44:37.095: INFO/dumpstate(17848): done
08-25 10:44:37.150: INFO/DEBUG(16421): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
08-25 10:44:37.170: INFO/DEBUG(17899): debuggerd: May 18 2011 13:55:14
08-25 10:44:37.270: INFO/ActivityManager(2689): Process com.test.android (pid 17236) has died.
08-25 10:44:37.285: INFO/WindowManager(2689): WIN DEATH: Window{40943ee0 com.test.android/com.test.android.activities.SecondScreenActivity paused=false}
08-25 10:44:37.290: INFO/WindowManager(2689): WIN DEATH: Window{40936210 com.test.android/com.test.android.activities.HomeScreenActivity paused=false}
08-25 10:44:37.290: INFO/WindowManager(2689): WIN DEATH: Window{4096f840 com.test.android/com.test.android.activities.ThirdScreenActivity paused=false}
08-25 10:44:37.290: INFO/WindowManager(2689): WIN DEATH: Window{409dea98 Select Language paused=false}
08-25 10:44:37.310: INFO/ActivityManager(2689): Start proc com.test.android for activity com.test.android/.activities.SecondScreenActivity: pid=17900 uid=10114 gids={3003, 1015}
```

Comment: Hello Mathew, Are You Store/Download Images in SD Card?

Comment: what is the Resolution of images? for eg. 128*128,72*72.

Comment: Please Provide Download Image Code Function.

Comment: Please Provide Some Code So I Can Check Your Code with My Code & I will Give You Answer of Your Question.

Comment: URL myFileUrl =null;  
  Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
  try {
   myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  try {
   HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
   connection.setDoInput(true);
   connection.connect();
   InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
   imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
  } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 12):

A lot of weird text in the beginning of the stack trace is native crash dump. Crash happens because of unhandled runtime error in one of the native libraries. The error happens because of accessing non-mapped address `0xdeadbaad`:

> 08-25 10:44:31.635: INFO/DEBUG(16421): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad

After this error application process is terminated and relaunched. `SecondScreenActivity` is created and then its state is restored from the last saved state.

**EDIT**: I don't think the problem is in your code. Seems it's an Android bug.
Here's a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14498.

This report contains the following conclusion:

> The APK is using Bitmaps from multiple threads, reusing it after it
>   has been (or while it is being) recycled.  The Skia graphics library
>   is not completely thread-safe, and introducing additional
>   synchronization is too expensive, so this won't be fixed in the
>   platform.
>
> So you need to be careful about what you `recycle()`.

Comment: I've added some possibly useful info for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.

First Declare All Variables/Objects Globally.

Then Use Following Function For Download Image in SDCard.

First Disply this Image in ImageView call following function on Click Event of Download Button.

```
Bitmap bmpImage;
bmpImage = loadBitmapFromView(imgview1);
downloadImageinphone(bmpImage);



public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(ImageView v) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        // v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
}
```

After Call this Function:-

```
Uri uri;
Bitmap b;

    private void downloadImageinphone(Bitmap b) {
        String filename = "tempImage";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, filename);
        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
        uri = getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                values);

        try {
            OutputStream outStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
            // outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            Log.d("done", "done");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Photo is Successfully Downloaded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        b.recycle();
    }
```