# Android - Process Has Died Issue

Tags: android, logging, crash, gps, android-mediaplayer

Application simply crashes and finishes the activity without much info.

```
04-01 13:30:43.739: W/AudioService(180): setMode() client died
04-01 13:30:43.739: W/GpsLocationProvider(180): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000
04-01 13:30:43.739: D/libloc(180): loc_eng_stop called
04-01 13:30:43.739: I/ActivityManager(180): Process com.company.android (pid 2590)has died.
04-01 13:30:43.739: W/ActivityManager(180): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.company.android/.utilities.OurGPSService in 80000ms
```

Log retrieved is much less, it simply shows that the process just died and causes our GPS Service to restart. Is it some ndk crash or something related to MediaPlayer? Please help in identifying the issue.

Comment: The `log_eng_stop`, isn't it from your application? That would mean something called a more or less "correct" shutdown. Of course question remains how to catch it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found 2 different answers to similar questions:

- [ActivityManager Process has died issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7266250/383414)

  - references an Android bug report with reusing bitmaps from different threads
- [Android process produces logcat “has died” message very often.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14748123/383414)

  - claims that this can just be normal behaviour in some cases

---

To add to this, I was chasing a crash where the `ApplicationManager` throws a `ClassCastException` from within the Android framework. Its only because I know I did a certain hack that I was able to determine that part of the trace was for my app.

The lesson I learnt is that sometimes the crash log has no evidence of your app's name. (The other lesson is that hacks always come back to bite the hacker...)

Comment: I am also getting similar issue frequently. The time is huge unlike some other apps.

Comment: The lesson here is invaluable.